Odd behavior across multiple PCs
PC1 = desktop 9900k/2060 Win 11 Pro
PC2 = multimedia 4790K/1030 Win 10 Home
PC3 = laptop i3/HD5500 Win 10 Home 
PC4 = desktop 7800X3D/4070 Win 11 Pro
The only common thing between them is my Microsoft account (sync is off). This happens on all 4 PCs:
The problem is that when logging in, the circle loading icon and cursor will stutter. Some say it's an Nvidia driver issue, that many experiences.
I hope someone has a solution.

What research have you done and what have you tried regarding the Language Selector? I know there are several questions on this site about the language selector icon and running different languages in your OS and inputs. Random stutters appears to be a different issue. You'll need to check Event Viewer and the Task Manager to track what resources are being maxed out when these stutters happen and add that info to your question.

Hey, so I managed to narrow it down. The language bar thing is a Windows bug, many have it. Fixed it by disabling it in registry.
The stuttering circle on login and occasionally opening apps etc. is an Nvidia driver bug. People suspect it's related to all the different resolution options in NVCP and DSC. So there isn't really a fix for it, but at least I know it's not on my end.

I recommend you edit the question then. Remove the part about the language bar because you've found the solutions to that elsewhere. Focus on the stuttering and stuff, note that you're aware it is because of the differing resolutions. Perhaps there isn't a fix for it, but perhaps there is, and someone here may have that little bit of particular knowledge to share regarding that.
